# A periodically independent stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Does there exist a non constant almost surely continuous stochastic process $X$ on $[0, \infty)$ with $X_t$ independent of $X_{t+1}$ for all $t  \geq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid answer: the trivial process $X_t=0$.

Less stupid answer: for every half-integer $n/2$, choose $X_{n/2}$ independently according to your favorite probability distribution and then interpolate linearly for other values of $t$.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to add nonconstant in the problem statement. Also yeah I suppose that works!